# Arrow heads on \twoheadrightarrow

Tags: symbols, arrows

The arrow heads on `\twoheadrightarrow` don't look like the arrow heads on `\rightarrow` and `\hookrightarrow`. Is there some way of fixing this?

For instance, the code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
\[ \hookrightarrow \twoheadrightarrow \rightarrow \]
\end{document}
```

produces an output as follows.

[image: Arrow heads]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could create your own `\rrightarrow`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amssymb
\usepackage{mathtools}% http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools
\newcommand{\rrightarrow}{\mathrel{\mathrlap{\rightarrow}\mkern1mu\rightarrow}}
\begin{document}
\[ \hookrightarrow \twoheadrightarrow \rrightarrow \rightarrow \]
\end{document}
```

`\rrightarrow` is an overlay of `\rightarrow` with a shifted version of itself. The length is `1mu` (one math unit) more than `\rightarrow`, which shouldn't deter too much from using it. You could also play with the kerning a bit, if needed.

Comment: I think it should be possible to "mask" the extra length off somehow. Possibly with some low level TeX box hackery.

Comment: If someone can figure out this "low level TeX box hackery," I'd definitely like to see how its done!

Answer (score 9):

Note that `\twoheadrightarrow` comes from `amssymb` package, while the other two are LaTeX predefined.

If you use the package `MnSymbol` they all are redefined and look the same.

Try the following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}

\begin{document}
\[ \hookrightarrow \twoheadrightarrow \rightarrow \]
\end{document}
```

and see whether they are fine (to me, they look better).

[image]

If you still need `amssymb` package for something else, you can load `MnSymbol` after it:

```
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
```