# Is it possible to crop glyphs?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, arrows

I want to crop `\rightarrow` so that the head remains but the tail is shorter. The reason I want a short-tailed rightarrow "`\shortrightarrow`" is because of my ultimate goal: to obtain a double headed arrow with the same width as the original.

In the [source2e](https://ctan.org/pkg/source2e?lang=en) `\rightarrow` is defined as follows:

```
393 \DeclareMathSymbol{\rightarrow}{\mathrel}{symbols}{"21}
```

RELATED: [Arrow heads on \twoheadrightarrow](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116460/arrow-heads-on-twoheadrightarrow)

With a "`\shortrightarrow`" I can easily construct the desired double headed rightarrow with the same width as the original. (n.b. `\twoheadrightarrow` has too small arrow heads; the answer provided in the above RELATED link does not have the same width as the original `\rightarrow`)

I tried to investigate how `\xrightarrow` is defined in hopes of being able to modify the code so that I can obtain a short-tailed `\rightarrow`. Unfortunately I found that the code uses `\cleaders` to render multiple copies of `\relbar`, so my investigation ended.

Now I resort to asking the TeX community for advice. Is it possible to crop glyphs?

EDIT: I want to provide an example of how I managed to create a custom `\hookrightarrow` so that the width is the same as `\rightarrow`. My ultimate goal is motivated by my recent ability to define `\inj`. (inj is short for injection; the double headed arrow will be used for surjection 'surj')

```
\newcommand{\inj}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\inj@{}}}
\newcommand{\inj@}[2]{\sbox0{$\m@th#1\lhook$}\ooalign{%
  $\m@th#1\rightarrow$\cr
  \smash{\fboxrule=0pt\fboxsep=0pt\fcolorbox{red}{white}{$\m@th#1\lhook\kern-.333\wd0$}}}}
```

Comment: erh, what is wrong with `\twoheadrightarrow` (from `amssymb`)? Found it the comprehensive LaTeX symbol list

Comment: @daleif The arrow heads are different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `trimclip`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,trimclip}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\tworightarrow}{\mathrel{\text{\two@rightarrow}}}
\newcommand{\two@rightarrow}{%
  \sbox0{$\m@th\rightarrow$}%
  \smash{\rlap{\kern0.1\wd0 \clipbox{{.3\width} {-\height} 0pt {-\height}}{$\m@th\rightarrow$}}}%
  $\m@th\rightarrow$%
}

\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.1pt}% just for the example

\begin{document}

\fbox{$\rightarrow$}

\fbox{$\tworightarrow$}

$a\rightarrow b$

$a\tworightarrow b$

$\tworightarrow \quad \scriptstyle \tworightarrow \quad \scriptscriptstyle \tworightarrow$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I recommend adjusting the clipbox's first argument to `\clipbox{{.3\width} {-\height} 0pt {-\height}}`. The difference is slight.

Comment: @AlbertoTakase Thanks, you've eagle eye.